# p:tree: cancel select event

Tags: primefaces

Is there a way to cancel a node's select event in a primefaces `p:tree` if a certain condition is true?

I would like to display a dialog and if the user choose the option "cancel" the selection should not be changed. 
I have tried calling a javascript function from p:ajax, but the new node is selected anyway.

```
<p:ajax event="select" onstart="showDialog()"/>
```

I have to override the Primefaces tree default behaviour?

---

PF6.2

Comment: Dit you try `onstart="return false;"`? Is it cancelled then?

Comment: You most likely also want that if the use cancels the action, the value is 'reset'? Otherwise there is an inconsistency in what the user sees and what the model contains. Right?

Comment: Ahhh... right. With onstart="return false;" the select is cancelled. For resetting the value I can just do an update of the component. Thx!

Comment: Well, it would be cool if we could cancel even the server selection event before it happens...

Comment: ??? Isn't that what the return false is doing

Comment: sorry, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly return a `false` in the `onstart` if you want to cancel the request.

```
onstart="return false;"
```

will cancel the request. And this means you need to return a true or false from the showDialog **AND** explicitly return that value in the onstart. So

```
onstart="return showDialog();"
```

Your challenge then is how to 'delay' the return of this javascript function so you can provide the return value of the user action.

Comment: In Javascript I can't wait for the user input. So I think the simpler solution would be onstart="showDialog();return false;" and than from the ok/cancel buttons of the Dialog execute the needed javascript (select or doNothing)

Comment: Well... You can do timeouts in javascript and if you make the dialog modal, the user has to do something so if the user did not do anything, do a new 100ms timeout... Might work...

Comment: And maybe even adding a `p:confirmDialog` inside the `p:ajax` \works? It just might....

Comment: Maybe I'll see if I can work up a generic PrimeFaces patch that makes the confirmDialog work this way. Won't be before coming monday unfortunately

Comment: I have noticed that if a have onstart="return false" the new node get highlighted anyway, is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: That is a new question. And do not forget that client-side everything is html, javascript and css and that the source of PrimeFaces is open. A valid answer to your question in your comment is: "Yes!"

Comment: Ok, probably I will remember the highlighted nodes and restore the old selection in the case the selection is cancelled. Thx for your time

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with this other solution: I have overridden 'nodeClick' of Primefaces VerticalTree widget, so that I can choose to display a Dialog OR to continue with the selection.

Here an example:

```
var param0, param1,param2;

function init() {
    PF('treeWidgetVar').nodeClick = function (b, a) {
        param0 = this;
        param1 = b;
        param2 = a;

        if(checkSomeCondition() == 'true'){
            showMyDialog();
            return;
        }else {
            PrimeFaces.widget.VerticalTree.prototype.nodeClick.call(this, b, a);
        }
    };
}

function doSelection(){
    PrimeFaces.widget.VerticalTree.prototype.nodeClick.call(param0, param1, param2);
}
```

I have used a JQuery UI confirm dialog. If the user click on "Continue" I do a selection with the savad params, otherwise I just close the dialog.

```
    $( function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: "auto",
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Continue": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    doSelection();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    } );
```

A little bit tricky but seems to work pretty well.